In VSCode window.title the variable ${workspaceFolderBasename} returns blank
I tried using ${workspaceFolderBasename} in vscode workspace file. As an example
my workspacefile path is something like C:\...\241101-01-sample.site\_.code-workspace
Workspace file is something like.
    "folders": [
        {
            "name": "--app--",
            "path": "-app"
        },
        {
            "name": "--site--",
            "path": "."
        },
        {
            "name": "--project--",
            "path": ".."
        },
    ],
    "settings": {
        "window.title": "[ ${workspaceFolderBasename} ] / ${folderName} ",
    }

In the title I believe I should be seeing: [ 241101-01-sample.site ] / --site--
But what I see is - [ ] / --site--. See the following image

Can't find anyone who has had this problem before. Please can anyone point me in the right direction?
I got the variable from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference
